# How to retrieve a Sharing Information object from SharePoint Online using CSOM?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm using the SharePoint Client Object Model to login into SharePoint online and then retrieve the Lists to get Documents on SharePoint. I then want to get the **shared link** for these documents. Here's how I am doing it at the moment:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteURL))
{
     context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
     context.Load(context.Web, w => w.Title);
     context.ExecuteQuery();

     List docList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
     context.Load(docList);
     // This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll"
     // so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in.
     CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
     ListItemCollection items = docList.GetItems(query);

     // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query).
     context.Load(items);
     context.ExecuteQuery();
     foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
     {
          var sharingInfo = ObjectSharingInformation.GetListItemSharingInformation(
             context, docList.Id, listItem.Id, false, true, false, true, true, true);

          context.Load(sharingInfo);
          context.ExecuteQuery();
          string str = sharingInfo.AnonymousEditLink;
     }
}
```

The issue here is that `sharingInfo` object has a field called AnonymousEditLink but it is an empty string. I'm not sure why this is an empty string. Is this the right way of going about generating a sharing link?

I have also tried this (but to no avail):

```
var sharingInfo = ObjectSharingInformation.GetObjectSharingInformation(
                    context, listItem, false, true, false, true, true, true, true);
```

I am referring to the method shown here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143612/how-to-retrieve-the-shared-link-of-a-file-programmatically

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? When I make a request it does not show users outside of the domain even though its displayed in the UI

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some work/testing with GetListItemSharingInformation and the AnonymousEditLink appears to get populated once the user has accessed the link the have received via email.

The same occurs with the SharedWithUsersCollection. Essentially, once the user has accessed the link. You'll find the properties are populated.